# Text next to radio button is not verticaly allign

Tags: html, css

Hello im trying to allign vertically text next to my radio-button, but its getting crashed.

```css
.radio {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.cui-a-radio-button__input {
  display: none;
}

.cui-a-radio-button__input:disabled  + .cui-a-radio-button-style {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.cui-a-radio-button-style {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
}
```

```html
<label for="Radio3" class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioField" id="Radio3" class="cui-a-radio-button__input" disabled>
    <div class="cui-a-radio-button-style">disabled</div>
</label>
```

I have tried to add "vertical allign: top" to label but id does not work.
Result i have:

[image]

Comment: The sample code does not produce the same result as shown in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding **align-items:center** on your radio class!

Answer (score 0):

for displaying a text beside radio button, just place the text inside your `input` tag. `label` tag is for another purpose.

```
    <input type="radio" disabled> disabled </input>
```